# What is a locations rep?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

the headline at NY Times i: 'How a rockaways locations rep spends her sundays'

I couldn't figure out what a location rep is, I imagine it has to do with tourism routes, Am I right? if so what exactly a location rep is?

Comment: From [the article itself...](https://goodwordnews.com/how-a-rockaways-locations-rep-spends-her-sundays/) *after her son left for college, Ms. Bloom, a weekend surfer, decided to embrace the scene full-time, so she moved to Arverne, an area near Rockaway Beach, Queens. Soon after, she started a new business, Rock Locations.* I don't know why she calls herself a "locations **rep**", when everyone else calls such people "locations **managers**", but the article (which seems to have been syndicated to many outlets) should make the meaning clear (it just describes what she does on her "day off").

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a job title that Claudia Bloom (in the article) made up for herself.

A "location" is the place where a video is shot.  People who make advertisements want cool locations.

She is hired by people who own cool places (like a surf shop, or a houseboat) and finds advertisers and content creators who want a location like this for their adverts.  She represents the location owners.

It's not a common phrase